# Unable to execute Sikuli script after i click on the Web-element. ( Selenium webdriver with Java)

Tags: java, selenium, sikuli

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws  InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        //Open the URL
        driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");
        //Maximize the window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //Click on Button which will open file upload window
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='photo']")).click();
        // Implementing Sikuli 
        ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
        Target target = new ImageTarget(new File("D://SELENIUM WORK-PLACE/File_upload//img//Capture.PNG"));
        ScreenRegion r = s.wait(target, 20000);
        r=s.find(target); // Locate the target on the screen.
        //Create a Canvas object of the type DesktopCanvas.
        Canvas test = new DesktopCanvas();
        test.addBox(r);
        test.addLabel(r, "I am present here");
        test.display(5);
    }   
    }
```

**Actual Result :** Clicks on the Web-element, It opens a File upload box. Nothing happens. ( But if i close the Box and re-open it manually then it works fine)

**Expected Output-** It should work at the first time  we open the File upload box.

Comment: what is "Capture.PNG" ? I mean, which image does it store ?

Comment: It is the name of my image  which is stored in my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Fix the path to: **"D://SELENIUM WORK-PLACE//File_upload//img//Capture.PNG"**

Then, try using the below image for getting the Filename textfield instead. Because bigger the size of image, there are more possibilities of Sikuli being unable to detect the element as even a pixel's change might get in the way of Sikuli identifying an element.:

[image]